# Mark an Adaptive card posted via Incoming webhook in MS Teams as done

Tags: microsoft-teams, webhooks, adaptive-cards

We get messages/tasks from an external PHP-server via incoming webhook in a Teams channel. They are posted in the Adaptive Card format using the ['message with attachments' method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook)

I would like to find a possibility to mark these messages as done.

My idea would be that the message has a button, that turns green and maybe changes the text when clicked. This has to be permanent. Also the text of the card should be hidden.

I tried to implement a button that toggles the visibility of the card, but it turns out the toggle is not persistent but gets reset every time the channel is opened.

As a workaround we are using reactions at the moment, but I would like to find a more obvious way.

Obviously an incoming webhook does not support the use of Action.Submit (as stated in the link above). So I cannot obviously update the card with this method.

I was thinking to use the Post adaptive card and await answer -method from Flow, but it cannot post an answer to a post, but only post a new card, so the context is missing, which of the posts in the channel you ant to mark as done.

A Power automate Flow could achieve this, if it could be told to alter the posted message.

I realize that it is actually a Task I want to post, not necessarily a message/card in a Teams channel. But there seems no way to post a new task directly to a Tasks tab in a Teams channel via an incoming webhook?

Has anybody an idea what technique could be used to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is possible using Actions with O365 connector card format, and is not a currently supported feature in Adaptive cards,**

[image]

Ref Doc: [⁠Create and send messages - Teams | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook)

Could you please raise an  [User Voice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)